# OutputStream write() method error

Tags: android

```
public class Streams extends Thread {

    private BluetoothSocket clientSocket;
    private InputStream input;
    private OutputStream output;

    public void Streams(BluetoothSocket s)
    {
        clientSocket = s;
        try {
            input = s.getInputStream();
            output = s.getOutputStream();
            Log.d("RTR","Got Socket Streams");
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("RTR","Unable to get Socket IO Streams");
        }

    }
    public void run()
    {
       //create an infinite loop for reading data.This method runs in seperate Thread

    }

    public void write(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        //output.write(bytes);
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error at last commented line `output.write(bytes)`.'`Cannot resolve method java.lang.Byte[]'`.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write()` method of `OutputStream` accepts `byte[]` object not `Byte[]` of `java.lang`

```
 public void write(byte[] bytes)
 {
        //output.write(bytes);
 }
```

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29)